# How to set button default selected in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've a `react code (snippet, not a complete code)` as shown below which shows list of timezones. On clicking a button, the timezone gets selected and it shows list of all programs.

```
const timezones = [{label:"PT",timezone:"America/Los_Angeles"},{label:"NT",timezone:"America/St_Johns"}];

const Picker = (props) => {
    console.log(props.selectedTimezone);  // Line Z
    return(
       timezones.map((timezoneObject) => {
           console.log(timezoneObject.timezone);  // Line Y
          return <li><button className={`${timezoneObject.timezone === props.selectedTimezone ? 'selected' : ''}`}
             onClick={(e) => {
             e.preventDefault();
             props.onChange(timezoneObject.timezone);
          }}>{timezoneObject.label}</button></li>
       })
    )
}
```

What I want achieve is when the page loads then the timezone `NT` should remain automatically selected without clicking a button. I've added `console.log(props) at Line Z` and I am getting `NT` on console but still
the `class selected` is not getting applied for `NT timezone`. `Line Y prints`:

```
America/Los_Angeles
America/St_Johns
```

Answer (score 0):

React does not store state information between requests. Every time you refresh the page, the state refreshes as well. However, you can use LocalStorage to accomplish this.

Here is a little snippet I found somewhere and adapted for one of the projects I'm working on:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useStickyState = (defaultValue, key) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    const stickyValue = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    return stickyValue !== null
      ? JSON.parse(stickyValue)
      : defaultValue;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
}

export default useStickyState;
```

Then in your component you can use it like this:

```
...
import useStickyState from '../../app/useStickyState';
...

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [timeZone, setTimeZone] = useStickyState('NT', 'timezone');
  ...
}
```

The first parameter of `useStickyState` is the default value and the second parameter is the name of the LocalStorage key to be used.